# How to load resource from jar before outside file in Java?

Tags: java, file, url, jar, classpath

I have the following problem:
I try to load a file from jar but I have the same file outside situated at the same relative path: "res/rtrconfig" as the file in jar. How can I ignore the outside file and get the jar file path?. I can't delete the outside file because other parts of my code need it.
   What I've got until now:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL url = loader.getResource(path);
        //check if file is in jar or not
        if (url == null) {
            System.err.println("FATAL: Properties file not found.Stopping the server.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        if ( !url.getProtocol().equals("jar")){

            System.err.println("Properties found outside jars.Please delete " + url.getPath() + " and re-start the server");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

This part of code checks if the file is founded in jar or in path.
I don't know how to configure URL to look after file in jar before file in path.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does the above code return? Isn't the resource found inside the jar? If not, what is the value of the path you are passing and the full name of the resource inside the jar?

Comment: "Properties found outside jars.Please delete " + here is an absolute path + " and re-start the server". res\rtrconfig is the name of the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all resources

```
Enumeration<URL> urls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResources(path);
```

file URL will have "file" protocol

```
    while (urls.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = urls.nextElement();
        if (url.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.I was heading that way but I didn't knew what to do with that Enum :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring this will work to get the jar resource file from outside jar.

ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("schema/feed.xsd");